# Update source to all excel links in word vba

Tags: excel, hyperlink, ms-word, vba

I am trying to update the source to all the links in a word report by using a macro in word VBA. I want to be able to offer a dialog box to user then they select file and it replaces current source in all links in the word doc. The code i have below works but really slowly. I also seem to have to open excel in the background or the links wont work? not sure why this is??

It seems to go through eack link in tuen. Is there a way to globally change all the links at the same time possibly using find and repalce? please any help is greatly appreciated! I need this for a reprot in work and so i need to find a solution as soon as possible.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim OldFile As String
    Dim xlsobj As Object
    Dim xlsfile_chart As Object
    Dim dlgSelectFile As FileDialog 'FileDialog object '
    Dim thisField As Field
    Dim selectedFile As Variant
    'must be Variant to contain filepath of selected item
    Dim newFile As Variant
    Dim fieldCount As Integer '
    Dim x As Long
    On Error GoTo LinkError
    'create FileDialog object as File Picker dialog box
     Set dlgSelectFile = Application.FileDialog
     (FileDialogType:=msoFileDialogFilePicker)
     With dlgSelectFile
     .Filters.Clear 'clear filters
     .Filters.Add "Microsoft Excel Files", "*.xls, *.xlsb, *.xlsm,  
     *.xlsx" 'filter for only Excel files
     'use Show method to display File Picker dialog box and return user's 
     action
     If .Show = -1 Then
      'step through each string in the FileDialogSelectedItems collection
      For Each selectedFile In .SelectedItems
      newFile = selectedFile 'gets new filepath
      Next selectedFile
      Else 'user clicked cancel
      Exit Sub
      End If
      End With
      Set dlgSelectFile = Nothing
      ' update fields



      Set xlsobj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
      xlsobj.Application.Visible = False
      Set xlsfile_chart = xlsobj.Application.Workbooks.Open(newFile,  
      ReadOnly   = True)

      Application.ScreenUpdating = False

      With xlsobj.Application
     .calculation = xlcalculationmanual
     .enableevents = False
      End With



       fieldCount = ActiveDocument.Fields.Count
        For x = 1 To fieldCount
         With ActiveDocument.Fields(x)
        If .Type = 56 Then
       .LinkFormat.SourceFullName = newFile
        End If
       End With
       Next x

          With xlsobj.Application
        .calculation = xlcalculationmanual
        .enableevents = True
         End With

         Application.ScreenUpdating = True



            MsgBox "Data has been sucessfully linked to report"

            'clean up
           xlsfile_chart.Close SaveChanges:=False
            Set xlsfile_chart = Nothing
           xlsobj.Quit
            Set xlsobj = Nothing


              Exit Sub
           LinkError:
          Select Case Err.Number
             Case 5391 'could not find associated Range Name
         MsgBox "Could not find the associated Excel Range Name " & _
       "for one or more links in this document. " & _
       "Please be sure that you have selected a valid " & _
       "Quote Submission input file.", vbCritical
       Case Else
       MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical
      End Select


      ' clean up
       Set xlsfile_chart = Nothing
       xlsobj.Quit
       Set xlsobj = Nothing

      End Sub
```

Comment: Just out of interest, are the files residing on a Network drive?

Comment: Yes, but when I update the links that is still fast. It's only changing source is slow

Comment: I was thinking could I find and replace the current file path for the links in the word doc would that be faster? I'm not sure how to do that though? Maybe using alt-f9

Comment: Can you provide an example of the type of change you are making? For example are you simply changing a folder name in a file path?

Comment: Yes simply changing the file path and file name. Essentially the full path would need to be replaced as the word report and excel may be copied to a different client folder and renamed.

Comment: The links within the excel sheet will always be the same as standard, it's just the file path will change. The actual links will always be the same

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim FolderName As String


With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
   .AllowMultiSelect = False
   .Show
   On Error Resume Next
   FolderName = .SelectedItems(1)
   On error go to 0
 End With

 If FolderName = "" Then
    Exit Sub
 End If

 'Continue with code using FolderName as your source path
```

Hopefully this will serve as a good starting point for you. This will get you the path of the source folder and store it in `FolderName`. You can then build your link using:

`CompletePath = FolderName + [FileNameGoesHere]`

(Don't forget to make sure your `FolderName` has a "\" on the end, else the path will be incorrectly formatted, if it doesn't you can add it in or perform a check to ensure it is present on the end of the `FolderName` string

Comment: Thanks but is that not the same as my dialog box where I call the source "newfile" in my code? Not sure how to find and replace the file path after that point?

Comment: How would I get the current source then I could use replace with new source? Do you know how to get current source in word vba?

Comment: No, your dialog box is searching for a complete path to a file, not just the folder in which it resides. Are all the links structured in the same way once dthey are in the source folder? For example `C:\Source\1\2\3` and you wish to change it to `C:\NewSource\1\2\3`. If this is the case then the `Source` section would become `FolderName` and you can freely switch it using the folderpicker as above. If the links are all over the place, you'll need a different method.

Comment: they are all in the same order so how would i do that using the folder picker? just use replace() function? how would i call the current source?

Comment: ideally i want the user to select the complete file path like in my dialog box and replace the current source file path with it? i think that would be faster than updating the source of the links like i am doing now, what do you think?

Comment: i might add there is only 1 excel file with all the sources in it so only 1 excel file for all the links, thats why i thought i might be able to just replace this path using replace()? what you think?

Comment: why is it that update links is so fast while change source is so so slow?